# Get particular parameter value from json object

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the factory defined, as shown below

```
app.factory('Category', function($resource,$rootScope) {
  return $resource('api/category');
});
```

This is my controller:

```
app.controller('ChartCtrl4', function ($scope, Category) {
   $scope.category = Category.get();
   $scope.totalCategory = ???      //total:2
});
```

data obtained from Category.get:

```
{
 message: "Category Retrieved Successfully",
 data: {
  total: 2,
  per_page: 10,
  current_page: 1,
  last_page: 1,
  next_page_url: null,
  prev_page_url: null,
  from: 1,
  to: 1,
  data: [
   {
    ...
   },{
    ....
   }
 ]
}
}
```

I want to access the value of **total** i.e **2** with in my controller.

Comment: `$scope.category.data.total`\

Comment: Cannot read property 'total' of undefined

Answer (score 1):

Try this one :

```
app.controller('ChartCtrl4', function ($scope, Category) {
   Category.get()
    .$promise.then(function(response) {
      $scope.totalCategory = response.data.total;
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var d = {
 message: "Category Retrieved Successfully",
 data: {
  total: 2,
  per_page: 10,
  current_page: 1,
  last_page: 1,
  next_page_url: null,
  prev_page_url: null,
  from: 1,
  to: 1,
  data: [
   {
    ...
   },{
    ....
   }
 ]
}
}
```

**d.data.total => 2**

Answer (score 0):

If I understand right, it should be: 
`$scope.category.data.total`
Maybe you are not familiar with `json`.
Here's a good article: http://www.webmonkey.com/2010/02/get_started_with_json/

Comment: I have done the same way.. but the error is .. Cannot read property 'total' of undefined

Comment: If it said: `Cannot read property 'total' of undefined `.I think it could be 2 reasons: 1- you don't have any data in your response (just add a if before). 2- You have to call the controller only after getting the resources

Answer (score 0):

$scope.category.data.total will get you the property, but it is wise to check to make sure the property actually exists and has a value before accessing it.

```
$scope.totalCategory = 0;

if ($scope.category && $scope.category.data && $scope.category.data.total) {
  $scope.totalCategory = $scope.category.data.total;
}
```

Just to be on the safe side.